# How to return a pandas dataframe with a rolling window but no additional function applied to it?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and I want to ignore (replace by NaN) values which do not have enough non-NaN values within a rolling window. Example dataframe can be recreated the following way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
for col in df.columns:
    df.loc[df.sample(frac=0.25).index, col] = np.nan  

       A     B     C     D
0   38.0  39.0   NaN  82.0
1   44.0  47.0   NaN   NaN
2    NaN  24.0  67.0   NaN
3   96.0   NaN   NaN  68.0
4   53.0   NaN  27.0  93.0
```

I want to create a rolling window with width of 4 and for each window, I want to only keep the value if there are at least `min_periods` non-NaN values there.

I thought this would be trivial simply by using:

```
df.rolling(4, min_periods=2).apply(lambda x: x)
```

However, it seems `apply` doesn't allow such lambda functions, and a `pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate` error is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the windows and keep only the ones that have a certain amount of nan values (or the opposite).

```
windowed_ds = df.rolling(4,min_periods=2)
windows_2_keep = []
for w in windowed_ds:
    # total nan values in window
    total_is_na_in_window = w.isna().sum().sum()
    # keep only windows with more than 2 nan values
    if total_is_na_in_window >2:
        windows_2_keep.append(w)
    # we can also do operations like mean or sum on each window
    # window_mean = w.mean().mean()
```

Comment: But `for` pretty much takes away all the advantages of pandas and it doesn't generalize well at all as the size of the dataframe increases. This solution would be extremely slow for dataframes with thousands of cols / rows.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is applying a custom function to the window that finds the nan values of the entire window and does any possible aggregation based on a condition. This is much faster that the for loop.

```
windowed_ds = df.rolling(4,min_periods=2)

def agg_function(ser):
    nan_counts = df.loc[ser.index].isna().sum().sum()
    print('window',df.loc[ser.index])
    
    print(nan_counts)
    # do mean only if the window has at least 2 nan values
    if nan_counts>2:
        print('window mean',df.loc[ser.index].mean().mean())
        print('--------------')
        return df.loc[ser.index].mean().mean()
    else:
        print('window mean',0)
        print('--------------')
        return 0
# returns a series (or a df based on the agg function of the window) with the
# aggregation result of each window. The selected column "A" is random and it
# just indicates how many times to run the function (agg_function) in the apply method

result = windowed_ds.A.apply(agg_function, raw=False)
```